# Invariant functions and Kac Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

I am solving the following exercise (1.2.1) from Viana & Oliveira's "Foundations of Ergodic Theory".

> Show that if $f: [0,1] \rightarrow[0,1]$ is a measurable transformation preserving the Lebesgue measure $m$ then $m$-almost everywhere $x \in [0,1]$ satisfies $$\liminf_n n|f^n(x)-x| \le 1.$$

Following the hint presented in the book, I will assume that the claim is false and try to reach an absurd using Kac's Theorem.

Suppose the claim is false. Then there is a set $B$ with $m(B)>0$ such that there exist a $b>1$ and a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n|f^n(x)-x|>b$ for every $n \ge k$.

We can take a density point $a$ of $B$ and  $r$ small enough such that the set $E=B\cap B(a; r)$ satisfies $m(E)>r$.

Now I am trying to find a lower bound to $\rho_E$, the transformation of first return to $E$. If I could show that $\rho(E)(x) >\frac{b}{r}$ for example, we would have
$$\int_E \rho_E \; dm \ge m(E)\cdot\frac{b}{r}\ge b>1,$$

and that would violate Kac's Theorem, but I am having trouble to show a fit lower bound. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we really find such $r$? The density theorem asserts $m(E)/r\to1$, but $m(E)<r$ for all $r$ is perfectly possible.

Comment: Fwiw the existence of such $B$ implies: $$1<\liminf_{n\to\infty}n\int_B|f^n(x)-x|\,\mathrm{d}\mu_B$$And Kac’s theorem says: $$\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\ge\frac{\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f^{-n}(B)\right)}{\mu(B)}=\int_B\rho_B(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu_B$$Perhaps $n|f^n(x)-x|$ can be related to $\rho_B$

Comment: Indeed we have: $$\mu(B)\int_B\rho_B\,\mathrm{d}\mu_B\le1<\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_Bn|f^n(x)-x|\,\mathrm{d}\mu_B(x)$$

Comment: Which is maybe a contradiction in disguise. This would be true if $B$ is replaced for any $E\subset B$ of positive measure (such subsets $E$ of arbitrary measure $0<\mu(E)<\mu(B)$ exist by the Sierpinski’s continuum of atomless measure theorem)

Comment: (if it is more useful, you can move the $\liminf$ inside the integral without changing the inequality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.
Repeating the first part of the argument:
Suppose the claim is false. Then there is a set $B$ with $m(B)>0$ such that there exist a $b>1$ and a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n|f^n(x)-x|>b$ for every $n \ge k$.

Since $B$ contains no fixed points of an iterate $f^j$, the   sets
$$B_\ell:=\{x \in B: \, \forall j \in [1,k], \quad |f^j(x)-x|>1/\ell\}$$
satisfy $\cup_{\ell \ge 1} B_\ell=B$, so
$m(B_\ell)>0$ for some $\ell$.

Choose a density point $a \ne 0,1$ of $B_\ell$ and fix $\delta>0$ such that $(2-\delta)b>2$. Then for  all  small enough $r$,   the set $E=B\cap (a-r,a+r)$ satisfies $m(E)>(2-\delta)r$. We fix such $r <1/(2\ell)$, and also require that $b/(2r)>k$.

Fix   $x \in E$.  For every $n \in [k , b/(2r)] $, we have
$$|f^n(x)-x|>b/n \ge 2r \,.$$
The inequality $|f^n(x)-x|> 2r$ also holds for $n \in [1,k]$, by our choice of $r$ and the definition of $B_\ell$.

Thus the return time   $\rho_E$ to $E$ satisfies $\rho_E(x)  \ge \frac{b}{2r}$ for all $x \in E$, so
$$\int_E \rho_E \; dm \ge m(E)\cdot\frac{b}{2r}\ge (2-\delta)b/2>1 \,,$$
contradicting Kac' lemma.

Comment: Very nice. I was on the wrong track completely

Comment: @CelioAugusto  Is my answer clear or should I clarify something?

Comment: @YuvalPeres It's perfectly clear, thanks!